# Pages by taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm creating a dummy website to learn Drupal 7. The idea is to build a car garage.

I added the *Cars* vocabulary, containing a list of car models.

- BMW

  - 1 serie

    - 1.18D
    - 1.20D
  - 3 serie

    - 3.30D
    - 3.35D
  - 5 serie
- Mercedes

  - A-Class
  - C-Class

I used the *Taxonomy Menu* module to display the vocabulary as a menu item in the main navigation.  I want the child terms to be shown on this page. When I click on a specific term, I would like it shows the child terms page.

I also installed the *Views* module, and made a view that would filter like by vocabulary machine name, but it show everything within the vocabulary.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a view, choose for Show: Taxonomy Terms instead of the default selected Content. 
Than you can define the Type of you terms and using a [contextual filter](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode39) (it is for Drupal 6, but the idea is the same) only show the terms that are a child of term page your on.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at the default replacement of the taxonomy pages supplied by views. The view has an argument that is a taxonomy term (i.e. show me a subset of cars based on the current URL/term) but there is a depth modifier that says also show me cars that are also tagged with the parent term or child terms (or not at all).